# Getting touchpad to work in desktop ubuntu

Tags: touchpad, input

I bought a small touchpad to stick on top of the keyboard, and it works fine on the windows computer, but not on my ubuntu desktop.

I mean, when I do "xinput list" it shows the following:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE                  id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600              id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Macintosh mouse button emulation          id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Cirque Corporation 9925 AG Touchpad       id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ No brand SP04-A1                          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Elite Silicon USB Audio Device            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The Cirque Corporation touchpad (I'm assuming that's the component name) is the touchpad. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try touchpad indicator. That may solve your problem.

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/touchpad-indicator-lets-you-quickly.html

Answer (score 0):

Typically input devices are handled by kernel modules or support is built into the kernel directly. For mice this tends to get handled by Xorg since most of the time a mouse is used with a GUI unless you are using `gpm` or something similar. Depending on the underlying driver you can typically install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` or something similar. In order to see whether the device is actually sending events you can run `xinput list` and then copy the device name and run `xinput test 'Device Name in single quotes'` to see whether it registers touches/taps/clicks.

Sometimes a particular library doesn't work well with your device and you may need to uninstall a driver (make sure you have a regular USB mouse just in case) or force the device to register with a different driver via Xorg.conf or a file in Xorg.conf.d (there are less options for configuration with Wayland in 18.04 currently).

You should also run `dmesg` and check the output after plugging in the device or you could run `dmesg --follow` and watch the changes after you plug in the device. This output can be helpful in diagnosing the issue.